# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'idUser' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to assign user roles in a flutter app. When sending the data to the table I get the following error. Testing the SQL queries with Postman, everything works OK. The problem is when sending from flutter.

I/flutter (26238): Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (26238): SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0
I/flutter (26238): ^
I/flutter (26238): Usuario elegido: 3
I/flutter (26238): Rol elegido: 3
E/flutter (26238): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'idUser' was called on null.
E/flutter (26238): Receiver: null
E/flutter (26238): Tried calling: idUser
E/flutter (26238): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (26238): #1      AdministratorRolesAssignController.assignRol (package:palser_delivery_app/src/pages/administrator/roles/assign/administrator_roles_assign_controller.dart:53:39)
E/flutter (26238): 
E/flutter (26238):

Model Rol

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';

Rol rolFromJson(String str) => Rol.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String rolToJson(Rol data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Rol {

  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String route;
  String idUser;
  String idRol;
  List<Rol> roles;
  List<Rol> toList = [];
  User user;

  Rol({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.image,
    this.route,
    this.idUser,
    this.idRol,
    this.roles,
    this.user,
  });

  // factory Rol.fromJson(Map<String, String> json) => Rol(
  factory Rol.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Rol(
    id: json["id"] is int ? json["id"].toString() : json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    image: json["image"],
    route: json["route"],
    idUser: json["id_user"],
    idRol: json["id_rol"],
    roles: json["roles"] == null ? [] : List<Rol>.from(json['roles'].map((model) => Rol.fromJson(model))) ?? [],
    user: json['user'] is String ? userFromJson(json['user']) : json['user'] is User ? json['user'] : User.fromJson(json['user'] ?? {}),
  );

  Rol.fromJsonList(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    if (jsonList == null) return;
    jsonList.forEach((item) {
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJson(item);
      toList.add(rol);
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "image": image,
    "route": route,
    "id_user": idUser,
    "id_rol": idRol,
    "roles": roles,
    "user": user,
  };

}
```

Roles Provider

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/api/environment/environment.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/response_api.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/roles_assignment.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/shared_pref.dart';

class RolesProvider {

  String _url = Environment.API_DELIVERY;
  String _api = '/api/roles';
  String _apiusers = 'api/users';

  BuildContext context;
  User sessionUser;

  Future init(BuildContext context, User sessionUser) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sessionUser = sessionUser;
  }

  Future<List<Rol>> getAll() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/getAll');
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) { // NO AUTORIZADO
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJsonList(data);
      return rol.toList;
    } catch(e) {
      print('ERROR: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<User>> getAllUsers() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_apiusers/getAll');
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) { // NO AUTORIZADO
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      User user = User.fromJsonList(data);
      return user.toList;
    } catch(e) {
      print('ERROR: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<Rol>> getRoles() async {
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/getRoles');
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) { // NO AUTORIZADO
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      Rol rol = Rol.fromJsonList(data);
      return rol.toList;
    } catch(e) {
      print('ERROR: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<ResponseApi> assignRol(Rol rol) async {
    try{
      Uri url = Uri.http(_url, '$_api/assign');
      String bodyParams = json.encode(rol);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': sessionUser.sessionToken
      };
      final res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: bodyParams);

      if (res.statusCode == 401) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Sesión expirada');
        new SharedPref().logout(context, sessionUser.id);
      }

      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      ResponseApi responseApi = ResponseApi.fromJson(data);
      return responseApi;
    }
    catch(e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

Controller

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/response_api.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/rol.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/provider/roles_provider.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/provider/users_provider.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/my_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:palser_delivery_app/src/utils/shared_pref.dart';

class AdministratorRolesAssignController {

  BuildContext context;
  Function refresh;

  SharedPref _sharedPref = new SharedPref();

  User user;
  List<User> users = [];
  UsersProvider _usersProvider = new UsersProvider();

  Rol rol;
  List<Rol> roles = [];
  RolesProvider _rolesProvider = new RolesProvider();

  String idUser;
  String idRol;

  Future init(BuildContext context, Function refresh, Rol rol) async {
    this.context = context;
    this.refresh = refresh;
    this.rol = rol;
    user = User.fromJson(await _sharedPref.read('user'));
    _usersProvider.init(context, sessionUser: user);
    _rolesProvider.init(context, user);

    getUsers();
    getRoles();
    refresh();
  }

  void assignRol() async {

    rol?.idUser = idUser;
    rol?.idRol = idRol;
    ResponseApi responseApi = await _rolesProvider.assignRol(rol);
    // MySnackBar.show(context, responseApi.message);

        print('Usuario elegido: ${idUser}');
        print('Rol elegido: ${idRol}');
        print('Usuario enviado: ${rol.idUser}');
        print('Rol enviado: ${rol.idRol}');
      // }
  }

  void getUsers() async {
    users = await _usersProvider.getAllUsers();
    refresh();
  }

  void getRoles() async {
    roles = await _rolesProvider.getRoles();
    refresh();
  }

}
```

I'm trying to assign user roles in a flutter app

Comment: you can provide default string on null case like `idUser: json["id_user"]?? "",`

Comment: You can't use `print('Usuario enviado: ${rol.idUser}');` if `rol` can be null. It appears as though you ran into this problem before and tried to fix it, but didn't apply the fix to all the locations where `rol.idUser` was being used.

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to overcome this problem. But now I got a message that I'm not realizing where the problem is.   

 I/flutter (26238): Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (26238): SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0
I/flutter (26238): ^
I/flutter (26238): Usuario elegido: 3
I/flutter (26238): Rol elegido: 4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.